# (Simple Python) CSV input to usernames

Tags: python, string, csv

I have a CSV file `names.csv`

```
First_name, Last_name
Mike, Hughes
James, Tango
, Stoke
Jack,
 ....etc
```

What I want is to be able to take the first letter of the `First_name` and the full `Last_name` and output it on screen as usernames but not include the people with `First_name` and `Last_name` property's empty. I'm completely stuck any help would be greatly appreciated

```
import csv 
ifile = open('names.csv', "rb") 
reader = csv.reader(ifile) 
rownum = 0 
for row in reader: 
    if rownum == 0: 
        header = row 
    else: 
        colnum = 0 
for col in row: 
    print '%-8s: %s' % (header[colnum], col) 
    colnum += 1 
    rownum += 1 
ifile.close()
```

Attempt #2

```
import csv
dataFile = open('names.csv','rb')
reader = csv.reader(dataFile)
next(reader, None)
for row in reader: 
    if (row in reader ) 
        print (row[0])
```

I haven't saved many attempts because none of them have worked :S

Comment: Shouldn't you give it a try, yourself ?

Comment: sorry the csv file entry's should be in rows of 2

Comment: i have been up for the past 5 hours ive been up all night

Comment: as I said help would be appreciated

Comment: post your attempts..

Comment: Don't post code in comments, edit your question to include your code (paste it there, highlight it, and press Ctrl-K to format it as code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv
dataFile = open('names.csv','rb')
reader = csv.reader(dataFile, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

for row in reader: 
    if not row[0] or not row[1]:
        continue
    print (row[0][0] + row[1]).lower()
```

Or

```
import csv
dataFile = open('names.csv','rb')
reader = csv.reader(dataFile, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

[(row[0][0] + row[1]).lower() for row in reader if 
                                      row[0] and row[1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the text from the .csv you can use the split() function to break up the text by the new lines. Your sample text is a little inconsistent, but if I understand you question correctly you can say

```
import csv
dataFile = open('names.csv','rb')
reader = csv.reader(dataFile)
reader = reader.split('\n')
for x in reader
    print(reader[x])
```

Or if you want to break it up by commas just replace the '\n' with ','

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this

```
from csv import DictReader

with open('names.csv') as f:
    dw = DictReader(f, skipinitialspace=True)

    fullnames = filter(lambda n: n['First_name'] and n['Last_name'], dw)
    for f in fullnames:
        print('{}{}'.format(f['First_name'][0], f['Last_name']))
```

You have headings in your csv so use a `DictReader` and just filter out those whose with empty first or last names and display the remaining names.